# Topic trigger for Google Cloud Function Github Action

Tags: google-cloud-functions, github-actions

How to define a topic trigger in a .yaml for Github actions for deploying a Google Cloud Function?

A working file with http (the default) is:

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions
name: CD

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "deploy"
  deploy:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Add "id-token" with the intended permissions.
    permissions:
      contents: "read"
      id-token: "write"

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - id: "auth"
        name: "Authenticate to Google Cloud"
        uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v0"
        with:
          # Replace with your Workload Identity Provider Location
          workload_identity_provider: "${PROJECT_VALUE}"
          # Replace with your GitHub Service Account
          service_account: "github-actions-service-account@${PROJECT_NAME}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

      - id: "deploy"
        uses: "google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@v0"
        with:
          # Name of the Cloud Function, same as the entry point name
          name: "${FUNCTION_NAME}"
          # Runtime to use for the function
          runtime: "nodejs16"
```

This thread has some suggestions but getting the topic ID is unclear
https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

adding the following works

```
- id: "deploy"
        uses: "google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@v0"
        with:
          # Name of the Cloud Function, same as the entry point name
          name: "${FUNCTION_NAME}"
          # Runtime to use for the function
          runtime: "nodejs16"
                    event_trigger_type: "google.pubsub.topic.publish"
                    event_trigger_resource: "projects/${PROJECT_VALUE}/topics/${TOPIC_ID}" //ie the string identifying the topic
                    event_trigger_service: "pubsub.googleapis.com"
```

The final issue was that having deployed a GCF with http trigger, that one had to be deleted before the above would successfully deploy